# CSS inline styling overriding for cms (Weebly) widget (Gallery)

Tags: html, css, dom

I am trying to override some inline style Weebly is using for their Gallery widget. The property I need to change is:

```
width: 33.28%
```

to

```
width: 100%
```

However, I can't seems to identify the id correctly to make the change.

This is the source code for Weebly's Gallery widget:

```
<div id="124908497214070465-imageContainer0" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;">
```

So I thought the id was "#124908497214070465-imageContainer0"

I entered this in the css:

```
#124908497214070465-imageContainer0 {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

However, it did not override the inline style.

I tried:

```
div#124908497214070465-imageContainer0 {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

and it didn't work as well.

As this point, I thought Weebly had some magic to prevent modification to their Gallery widget's code. However when I did a  styling:

```
div {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

The width of the image changed from width:33.28% to 100%. However, this isn't an option as it messes with the other div tags as well.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: the styling looks like its added via the galleries javascript - wouldn't it be easier if you find the js file and change the values there ?

Answer (score 1):

> ID must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

From the [HTML specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)...

**OR**

Manually add `class` to that `div` and override it.

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/041xmamo/)

Comment: what of your answer help the OP's problem? this just should put in comment section

Comment: I did not know that, thanks for the info. So does that means it is impossible to override the inline styling that comes with the gallery widget with a `!important` in the main CSS?

Comment: @HenryVarro I am giving him the reason why it is not overriding his styles.

Comment: You can do it manually you can add class to that div and override it. just like this https://jsfiddle.net/041xmamo/

Comment: @SrinivasPai yes i know but like i said what it help the OP solve his problem? An answer should not only point the error (if it exist) but also provide solution(s) to solve the OP problem, right?

Comment: @HenryVarro thanks Henry, I had found the solution after Googling about ways of selecting id that starts with numbers thanks to SrinivasPai comment :) cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys I found the solution, to select a numeric id in css, you just have to do this:
    [id="id"]

So in my case, I simply need to:
    [id="124908497214070465-imageContainer0"] to override the inline styling.